# How to make conditional statements more compact in C?

Tags: c, conditional-statements

I have a code snippet that uses `if-else if-else` block. I am wondering any potential ways to shorten the lengthy conditional statement `else if (cardLength == 16) && (numberArray[0] == 5 && (numberArray[1] == 1 || numberArray[1] == 2 || numberArray[1] == 3 || numberArray[1] == 4 || numberArray[1] == 5))`, for instance, without changing the logic. In python, I can do in this way: `if (cardLength == 16) and (numberArray[0:2] in range(51,56))`. Are there any specific syntax sugar that I can use fo this purpose in C?

```
if (cardLength == 15) &&
   (numberArray[0] == 3 && (numberArray[1] == 4 || numberArray[1] == 7))
{
    printf("AMEX\n");
}
else if (cardLength == 16) &&
        (numberArray[0] == 5 && (numberArray[1] == 1 || numberArray[1] == 2 || numberArray[1] == 3 || numberArray[1] == 4 || numberArray[1] == 5))
{
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
}
else if (cardLength == 13) && (numberArray[0] == 4)
{
    printf("VISA\n");
}
else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

Comment: Instead of `numberArray[1] == 1 || numberArray[1] == 2 || numberArray[1] == 3 || numberArray[1] == 4 || numberArray[1] == 5` perhaps `numberArray[1] >= 1 && numberArray[1] <= 5`?

Comment: On another note, it's not always desirable to have more "compact" code, as that often tend to make the code harder to read and understand, as well as maintain. Compilers are also pretty smart so often more "compact" code doesn't have to mean the code is more effective after the compiler optimizes it.

Comment: I don't think you can meaningfully compact that code, without changing "techniques". I.e. you could make some regex-like validation or construct a pattern-matching DSL, but what you have works well and is pretty minimal

Comment: What is the full name of DSL?

Comment: To check if an integer `n` is in the range `a` to `b`, just use `n >= a && n <= b`.  There's no need to check every single value within that range.  Even in Python, you would use `a <= n <= b`.  You wouldn't construct a `range` object to make the test (unless you want to slow down your code).

Comment: My Visa card has 16 digits. Are you sure this is right?

Comment: DSL = domain-specific language. A mini-language made up for a specific task.

Comment: Another approach might be to *generate* that C code with tools like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)

Comment: The correct way would be to come up with a generic card struct, then use a comparison function per type of card, which can be used to tell if a card is of that type or not. This requires that you are familiar with structs, function pointers and so on however.

Comment: The code will not compile due to missing parentheses in the `if` statements.

Comment: leverage the comparisons into separate functions.
It doesn't solve the redundant comparisons, but it makes the code more readable.
https://pastebin.com/FT9e5qgZ

Answer (score 4):

Put it into a (static) function. Dont think about performance/optimisation yet.

---

```
static char *card_leng_type2string( unsigned len, int *arr)
{
if (len == 15 && arr[0] == 3 && arr[1] == 4 ) return "AMEX";
if (len == 15 && arr[0] == 3 && arr[1] == 7 ) return "AMEX";
 
if (len == 16 && arr[0] == 5 && arr[1] == 1 ) return "MASTERCARD";
if (len == 16 && arr[0] == 5 && arr[1] == 2 ) return "MASTERCARD";
if (len == 16 && arr[0] == 5 && arr[1] == 3 ) return "MASTERCARD";
if (len == 16 && arr[0] == 5 && arr[1] == 4 ) return "MASTERCARD";
if (len == 16 && arr[0] == 5 && arr[1] == 5 ) return "MASTERCARD";

if (len == 13 && arr[0] == 4) return "VISA";

return "INVALID";
}
```

---

Now your calling code could just do:

```
printf("%s\n", card_leng_type2string(cardLength, numberArray) );
```

Comment: I actually like the repeated expressions in this case -- they make everything much clearer.  I had initially misread the original code as calling for sequences like `347`.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number), VISA card numbers may be either 13 or 16 characters. AMEX and Mastercard look okay.

Comment: @SteveSummit: at least it is easier to read and to edit. And it could later be refactured (into table-based data, or returning an enumeration instead of a constant string)

Comment: @LucaPolito : I dont care about the literals/constants. I just tried to copy/mimick the questions behaviour.

Comment: @wildplasser I like this approach too. At least in C, it is the only way to make it both readable and compact, without long `if` conditions (and without using separate functions for each validation). It is still very redundant, but it's a flaw of C, I'm afraid. P.S.: about the numbers, yea I know, but I pointed that out so whoever reads the answer doesn't copy the wrong VISA validation.

Comment: Should return `const char*` though.

Comment: The suggestion to encapsulate the code in a function is almost always an excellent one.  Not only does it make the calling code easier to read, but once you have an encapsulated function, it's easy to wrap a unit test around it, and once you have a unit test, you can rewrite the function later (perhaps in a "more efficient" but less clear way) with impunity.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the first two digits of the `numberArray` into a new number like this

```
num = numberArray[0]*10 + numberArray[1]
```

and then use that into the conditional statements to make them more readable

```
int num = numberArray[0]*10 + numberArray[1]

if ((cardLength == 15) && ((num == 37) || (num == 34)))
{
    printf("AMEX\n");
}
else if ((cardLength == 16) && ((num >= 51) && (num <= 55)))
{
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
}
else if ((cardLength == 13) && ((num >= 40) && (num <= 49)))
{
    printf("VISA\n");
}
else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, although it leaves the reader scratching his head: Why isn't the last case `if(cardLength == 13 && num == 4)`?

Comment: Also, this implementation has a number of small mistakes: The initial `num` computation needs character → digit conversions; the AMEX clause shouldn't allow 35 and 36; the Mastercard clause shouldn't allow 56; the VISA clause needs to check for `'4'` not `4`, and all the `if` statements need one more pair of parentheses.  (I'm guessing you didn't compile this before you posted it. :-) )

Comment: @SteveSummit you were right about most things. I corrected the syntactical errors you found (and yeah I did not compile it ;-) )

Comment: The last case should be `numberArray[0] == 4` instead of `num >= 40`

Comment: @hmhuang `num` is a double digit number because it is formed by the first 2 elements of the `numberArray`. So we its value must be between 40 and 49

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that entries in `numberArray` are in range 0-9, you could use `strchr` function. This returns non-NULL if a given string contains a specific character.

Replace:

```
numberArray[1] == 4 || numberArray[1] == 7 || numberArray[1] == 9
```

with

```
strchr("479", '0' + numberArray[1])
```

If `numberArray` was an array of character then the check could be simplified to `strchr("479", numberArray[1])`

Answer (score -1):

If you want the logic intact and only want modification for readbility, you could try adding a preprocessor directive gloabally.
This would replace the text or inline function anywhere you use it in the program.
Example

```
#define AMEX_CONDITION (cardLength == 15) &&  (numberArray[0] == 3 && (numberArray[1] == 4 || numberArray[1] == 7))
```

and use it in your if as

```
if(AMEX_CONDITION){
    printf("AMEX");
}
```

Comment: This decreases readability. I would suggest adding some `static inline`  function

Comment: Inventing your own secret macro language is a very bad idea. This is much worse than what the OP already had.

Comment: RE: use of macros: based on my experience macro substitutions are common and effective in SW engineering (OS and real-time, embedded systems)...

Comment: @MartinKuester I work almost exclusively with real-time embedded systems and from my experience, macros like these are mostly used when the programmer is oblivious to function inlining or how modern compilers generate code in general. Or when they are confused in some other way, like when inventing some magic macro language just to do simple GPIO bit manipulations.